# Hyperlink on text adds url to output

Tags: resume

I am using latex to build my resume.
I am trying to hyperlink an entire paragraph.

I am refering the official overleaf documenattion for using hyperlinks.
They mention to use the `\href{url}{text}` to combine hyperlink with text.

Unfortunately, I have some additional tags that I want to combine my hyperlink with.

```
\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{paragraph_title}{paragraph_description}
```

What I tried:

```
\href{url}{

    \cvachievement{\faTrophy}{paragraph_title}{paragraph_description }
}

But this also adds the URL to the final output. How do I fix this?
```

Comment: You should show a small but *complete* example so that your issue can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no working (complete) example to test what I'm saying. Also I'm not entirely sure what errors you get (if any).

BUT, have you tried to add the `\href` into the brackets?

For instance:

```
\providecommand{\achieved}[3]{\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{\href{#3}{#1}}{\href{#3}{#2}}}
```

You just call it with `\achieved{paragraph_title}{paragraph_description}{url}`.

Hope that helps.